# how to calculate response time of a website in java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, swing, jakarta-ee

I am trying to build a website monitoring system.I need to calculate the time taken by a website to response or total load time.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you investigated some tool or anything that can help you with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the round trip between http request and response, you could use [apache http components](http://hc.apache.org/). This used to be called apache http client.

Here's some sample code I'm using for making requests. You could just grab a timestamp before and after the request.

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    URI uri = null;
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("json" + File.separator + "newInstall.json");
    try {
        String json = FileUtil.readFile(url.getPath());
        builder.setScheme("http").setHost(host).setPort(8080).setPath(basePath + authResource)
                .setParameter("sig", "sig").setParameter("params", json);
        uri = builder.build();
        log.info("uri: {}", uri);
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            log.info("auth response: {}", jsonString);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error", e);
    }finally {
        if(inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                log.error("error closing input stream", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```